# Doubly periodic function and Basis

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

While Studying Elliptic function I found this theorem which I post below

There exists a basis$ (\omega _1 , \omega _2)$ such that the ratio $\tau=\frac{\omega _2}{\omega _1}$ satisfies the following conditions :

1. $ Im(\tau )>0$
2. $\frac{1}{2} < Re (\tau) \leq \frac{1}{2}$
3. $|\tau|\geq1 $
4. $Re( \tau) \geq 0 $ if $|\tau|=1$

the ratio  $\tau$ can be uniquely determined by these conditions, and there is a choice of two , four or six corresponding bases

And the proof goes like this,

If we select $ (\omega _1 , \omega _2)$ as $\tau=\frac{\omega _2}{\omega _1}$  , Then

$|\omega_1 ,||\omega_2 | \leq |\omega_1 + \omega_2  |$ and $|\omega_2 | \leq |\omega_1 -\omega_2  |$

**In terms of $\tau $ this conditions are equivalent to $|\tau| \geq 1$ and $ Re (\tau ) \leq \frac{1}{2} $**

I didn't get how comes the last statement.Any Help leading to answer  will be Appreciable ...!

Comment: See the grey region [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Tessellation_of_the_hyperbolic_plane) (a fundamental domain for $\mathbb{H}/SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
|\omega _1|\le |\omega _2|,\quad |\omega _2|\le |\omega _1+\omega _2|, \quad|\omega _2|\le |\omega _1-\omega _2| \iff |\tau|\ge 1,\quad |\operatorname{Re }\tau|\le \frac{1}{2}$$
Proof. First $$
|\omega _1|\le |\omega _2|\iff |\tau|\ge 1$$
because $\tau=\omega_2 /\omega _1.$
Next \begin{align}
&|\omega _2|\le |\omega _1+\omega _2|, \quad|\omega _2|\le |\omega _1-\omega _2|\\
\iff& |\omega_2 /\omega _1|\le |1+\omega_2 /\omega _1|,\quad |\omega_2 /\omega _1|\le |1-\omega_2 /\omega _1| \\
\iff &|\tau|\le |1+\tau|,\quad|\tau|\le |1-\tau|\\
\iff&|\tau|^2\le|1+\tau|^2,\quad|\tau|^2\le |1-\tau|^2\\
\iff&\tau\bar{\tau}\le (1+\tau)(1+\bar{\tau}),\quad \tau\bar{\tau}\le (1-\tau)(1-\bar{\tau})\\
\iff & 0\le 1+2\operatorname{Re }\tau,\quad 0\le 1-2\operatorname{Re }\tau\\
\iff& -1/2\le\operatorname{Re }\tau\le 1/2.
\end{align}